# C# async/await progress reporting is not in expected order

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await, progress

I am experimenting with async/await and progress reporting and therefore have written an async file copy method that reports progress after every copied MB:

```
public async Task CopyFileAsync(string sourceFile, string destFile, CancellationToken ct, IProgress<int> progress) {

  var bufferSize = 1024*1024 ;
  byte[] bytes = new byte[bufferSize];
  using(var source = new FileStream(sourceFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)){
    using(var dest = new FileStream(destFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)){

      var totalBytes = source.Length;
      var copiedBytes = 0;
      var bytesRead = -1;
      while ((bytesRead = await source.ReadAsync(bytes, 0, bufferSize, ct)) > 0)
      {
        await dest.WriteAsync(bytes, 0, bytesRead, ct);
        copiedBytes += bytesRead;
        progress?.Report((int)(copiedBytes * 100 / totalBytes));
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In a console application a create I file with random content of 10MB and then copy it using the method above:

```
private void MainProgram(string[] args)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Create File...");
  var dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(MainClass).Assembly.Location);
  var file = Path.Combine(dir, "file.txt");
  var dest = Path.Combine(dir, "fileCopy.txt");

  var rnd = new Random();
  const string chars = ("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890");
  var str = new string(Enumerable
                       .Range(0, 1024*1024*10)
                       .Select(i => letters[rnd.Next(chars.Length -1)])
                       .ToArray());
  File.WriteAllText(file, str);

  var source = new CancellationTokenSource();
  var token = source.Token;

  var progress = new Progress<int>();
  progress.ProgressChanged += (sender, percent) => Console.WriteLine($"Progress: {percent}%");

  var task = CopyFileAsync(file, dest, token, progress);
  Console.WriteLine("Start Copy...");
  Console.ReadLine();
}
```

After the application has executed, both files are identical, so the copy process is carried out in the correct order. However, the Console output is something like:

```
Create File...
Start Copy...
Progress: 10%
Progress: 30%
Progress: 20%
Progress: 60%
Progress: 50%
Progress: 70%
Progress: 80%
Progress: 40%
Progress: 90%
Progress: 100%
```

The order differs every time I call the application. I don't understand this behaviour. If I put a Breakpoint to the event handler and check each value, they are in the correct order. Can anyone explain this to me?

I want to use this later in a GUI application with a progress bar and don't want to have it jumping back and forward all the time.

Comment: You need a synchronization context for IProgress and you should also add ConfigureAwait(false) to the awaiting task in CopyFileAsync() method

Comment: `Progress<T>` is using a synchronization context to handle the invocation of the event handler, and as such have no guarantee that the event handler will be invoked in the same order as your call to `.Report`, this depends entirely on the specific synchronization context in use at the time and its behavior.

Comment: As a side note: if you want a FileStream to actually read and write asynchronously you need to create it with the constructor using the FileOptions.Asynchronous parameter. Otherwise it is just using a thread to give the illusion of an asynchronous IO operation.

Comment: The file copy is just too fast to have any hope that all the threadpool threads started by ProgressChanged will be able to acquire the console lock in the expected order.  Pretty standard test problem, the file system cache makes the disk look very fast.  Just a memory-to-memory copy.  You will not have this problem in a GUI app, the updates will be strictly ordered by the dispatcher loop.

Comment: Thanks @ckuri I did not know this option. Even in the [MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh158629(v=vs.110).aspx) they don't use it. It is only mentioned in the constructor doc.

Comment: @HansPassant: You are right. When I increase the file size to 50 MB and the buffer to 5MB, the order is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Progress<T>` captures current `SynchronizationContext` when created. If there is no `SynchronizationContext` (like in console app) - progress callbacks will be scheduled to thread pool threads. That means multiple callbacks can even run in parallel, and of course order is not guaranteed.

In UI applications, posting to synchronization context is roughly equivalent to:

1. In WPF: `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke()`
2. In WinForms: `Control.BeginInvoke`

I'm not working with WinForms, but in WPF, multiple `BeginInvoke` with the same priority (and in this case they are with the same priority) are [guaranteed](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms591587.aspx) to execute in order they were invoked:

> multiple BeginInvoke calls are made at the same DispatcherPriority,
>   they will be executed in the order the calls were made.

I don't see why in WinForms `Control.BeginInvoke` might execute our of order, but I'm not aware of a proof like I provided above for WPF. So I think in both WPF and WinForms you can safely rely on your progress callbacks to be executed in order (provided that you created `Progress<T>` instance itself on UI thread so that context could be captured).

Site note: don't forget to add `ConfigureAwait(false)` to your `ReadAsync` and `WriteAsync` calls to prevent returning to UI thread in UI applications every time after those `await`s.

Comment: Sounds right, I'll test it on Monday when I'am back in the office, since I have no Windows PC to test WPF at home :)